# Using affinity in devices

Tags: redhawksdr

The use of affinity to control cpu and other resources of a component appears to be a new feature in RedHawk 2.1.  The manual only describes its use in Resource components but I would like to use it in a Device.  I tried adding the  block for cpu to the DCD  for the device but it appeared to have no affect.  Is there a way to control affinity for a Device in RedHawk?

Comment: I am able to set the cpu set using sched_setaffinity() but it would be nice to do it in the DCD rather than in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Section 10.4 Describes how to add the affinity section to the DCD file.  The same affinity directives for a Components are available for Devices and Sevices.  Consult section 7.3.5 Resource Affinity for more detailed information.  You can provide a cpu set using the following:
`<affinity>
   <simpleref id="affinity_class" value="cpu />
   <simpleref id="affinity_value" value="1-7" /> 
</affinity>`
The value is any valid string that numa_parse_cpustring accepts.

The caveat is the stock rpms for REDHAWK are not compiled with --enable-affinity=yes.  So you will need to recompile the framework  to take advantage of these options.

Answer (score 0):

The Device Manager is responsible for deploying Devices and Services. Check if [section 10.4](https://redhawksdr.github.io/Documentation/mainch10.html#x12-25100010.4) of the documentation answers your question.

> To enable affinity processing by the Device Manager, build the REDHAWK
>   software with the affinity option enabled